# GitHub unicorn when creating PR: "This page is taking too long to load."

Tags: github

When creating a Pull Request on GitHub, the page refuses to load and I am instead shown a unicorn error message:

[image: GitHub Unicorn - This page is taking too long to load.]

> This page is taking too long to load.
>
> Sorry about that. Please try refreshing and contact us if the problem persists.

This repo's [default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/changing-the-default-branch) is set to `master`, which is *well behind* the development branch we merge into. This error is likely a result of there being too many commits or the resulting PR being "too big".

Is there another URL or method to create a PR without calculating the full diff of the default branch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you push a branch, GitHub will helpfully show a `Compare & pull request` button as a shortcut to creating a PR for that branch:

[image: Compare & pull request]

That button is useful in most circumstances, but does automatically compare against the default branch using this URL:

> https://github.com/user/repo/compare/branch?expand=1

If the resulting diff is too big or complicated, the unicorn error message will be shown.

Instead, press the `New pull request` button. The subsequent page will allow you to select the PR's `base` and `compare` branches *prior to generating the diff*.

> https://github.com/user/repo/compare

The diff into your development branch will be simpler, and you should no longer get the error.

Comment: This doesn't work if the changes are in a single commit/branch :(

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve by creating the PR via the GitHub API e.g.

```
gh api \
  --method POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls \
  -f title='Amazing new feature' \
  -f body='Please pull these awesome changes in!' \
  -f head='octocat:new-feature' \
  -f base='master'
```

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls#create-a-pull-request